# File delete using FOR loop in makefile

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

I got struck in writing FOR loop to delete object files in clean target. I tried the below code however I'm getting error message. Could any one please help me on this?

```
TES_FILE := D:/Technique/Testmake/1.obj
TES_FILE += D:/Technique/Testmake/2.obj

clean:
$(foreach objFile,$(TES_FILE),if exist $(objFile) DEL /F "$(subst /,\,$(objFile))")
```

error message:

> Error Message: if exist D:/Technique/Testmake/1.obj DEL /F "D:\Technique\Testmake\1.obj" if exist D:/Technique/Testmake/2.obj DEL /F "D:\Technique\Testmake\2.obj" Invalid switch - "Technique". gmake: * [clean] Error 1

Thanks,
Anand

I'm reposting this question as I have not received any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make's `foreach` function is a *textual substitution*.  It doesn't actually invoke a different shell or command for each "body" of the `foreach`.  So the result of make's `foreach` is simply the result of appending all those instances of the body together.  For example:

```
$(foreach A,W X Y Z,$(A) $(A))
```

yields the single string `W W X X Y Y Z Z`.  In your case, it yields a single string containing the concatenation of all the `if` statements.  Which of course won't work.

If you mentioned *why* you felt you needed a `foreach` in the first place it would be easier to help.  If it were me I'd just write:

```
clean:
       DEL /F $(subst /,\,$(TES_FILE))
```